# Creating Android styles dynamically

Tags: android, android-styles, android-custom-attributes

I have a hard time finding any information on whether it is possible to create a custom `Style` from scratch that was not defined in the `resources` at the time a given build was created.

My goal is to change the look and feel of the app based on external input at any given time. Can you help me on this please?

Example: I want to edit these values

```
<resources>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: *I have a hard time finding* ... well, I found pretty quick that it is not possible

Comment: can you provide some links to it please?

Comment: *My goal is to change the look and feel of the app based on external input* at runtime? not possible! at build the time? it's easy ... for example with [gradle](https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/f89476b6585690cb252b) will generate [something like](https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/8e673e38c5fed8e2132b)

Comment: If I get this right, you still have to create a new build to get things done, right?

Comment: yes, but with variants it is really quick

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but still it is good information. Thanks!

Comment: `Change the look and feel of the app based on external input at any given time.` Can you give an example?

Comment: I posted an example of what I want to change.

Comment: [new version](https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/ec9a639f3e9495b012ed6958edff7ca2) with samples